# Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type '_?'

Tags: swift

*Note: I'm a rookie in Swift*

I'm using [Former](https://github.com/ra1028/Former).

I'm fetching data from a realm model.

```
let industries = realm.objects(Industry)
```

Then I try to define a list of `InlinePickerItem` from it:

```
$0.pickerItems = industries.map({ industry in
    return InlinePickerItem(title: industry.name, value: industry.id)
})
```

But XCode keeps saying: `Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type '_?'`, pointing to `industry.id`.

Am I missing something? I don't know if the issue comes from Former or from something that I don't understand in Swift. For example, what kind of type is `_?`?

**UPDATE**:

After @dfri comment, attempt was unsuccessful. From my small understanding of Swift, I get that Swift gets lost. So I extracted the initialisation of the list of `InlinePickerItem` from the closure.

```
    let industries = realm.objects(Industry)
    let inlinePickerItems = industries.map({ industry in
        return InlinePickerItem(title: industry.name, displayTitle: nil, value: industry.id)
    })
    let catRow = InlinePickerRowFormer<ProfileLabelCell, String>(instantiateType: .Nib(nibName: "ProfileLabelCell")) {
        $0.titleLabel.text = "CATEGORY".localized
    }.configure {
        $0.pickerItems = inlinePickerItems
    }
```

The error is disappeared when calling `InlinePickerItem(title: industry.name, displayTitle: nil, value: industry.id)` but I get something new when assigning it to `$0.pickerItems` which now is:

```
Cannot assign value of type '[InlinePickerItem<Int>]' to type '[InlinePickerItem<String>]'
```

Hope this will provide you with some helpful hints.

Comment: If you option-click on `industries`, what type is it?

Comment: @vacawama It's of type `Industry`. @dfri Thanks, I'll try this.

Comment: @dfri I've tried the modification you proposed but the error persists exactly the same. I've updated the post with some new hints starting from what you proposed. Maybe you'll have new insights.

Comment: @dfri THANKS ! I just changed the type of `catRow` to `InlinePickerRowFormer<ProfileLabelCell, Int>` and it works smoothly. You want to write an answer? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Type mismatch when assigning array to different type array

After the re-factoring of your code (after *"update"*) its now apparent what is the source of error.

Immutable `catRow` is of type `InlinePickerRowFormer<ProfileLabelCell, String>`. From the source of [InlinePickerRowFormer] we see the that the class and its property `pickerItems` is declared as follows

> ```
> public class InlinePickerRowFormer<T: UITableViewCell, S where T: InlinePickerFormableRow>
> : ... {
>
>     // ...
>
>     public var pickerItems: [InlinePickerItem<S>] = []
>
>     // ...
> }
> ```

The key here is that for an instance `InlinePickerRowFormer<T,S>` its property `pickerItems` will be an array with elements of type `InlinePickerItem<S>`. In your example above `S` is `String`

```
let catRow = InlinePickerRowFormer<ProfileLabelCell, String>
                                               /*       |
                                                        S = String */
```

Hence `pickerItems` is an array of `InlinePickerItem<String>` instances.

You try, however, to append the immutable `inlinePickerItems` to `pickerItems`, which means you're trying to assign an array of `InlinePickerItem<Int>` instances to an array with elements of type `InlinePickerItem<String>`; naturally leading to a type mismatch.

You can solve this type mismatch by:

- Setting your `catRow` immutable to be of type `InlinePickerRowFormer<ProfileLabelCell, Int>`.